# Rails omniauth and regular login, giving an undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth

I have used Rails Tutorial's instructions to create a working login. And then later to add Google authorization I used the omniauth method.

However, whenever I sign in using the Google account, I get an error in the sessions_controller. Where it says:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:N
ilClass): app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

I am adding the sessions_controller

Sessions_controller.rb

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def create_from_omniauth
    @user = User.from_provider_data(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to user
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def google_destory
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

How do I resolve this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because it's `ENV`, not `env`.

```
@user = User.from_provider_data(env["omniauth.auth"])
```

to

```
@user = User.from_provider_data(ENV["omniauth.auth"])
```

unless `env` is something defined by you